# save pdf file in a folder using mPDF

Tags: pdf, drupal-7, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using mPDF to generate pdfs. I want to know, how to save that file to a particular folder path. I am using this code to save the file :

```
$path = "sites/default/files/diet_plans/diet_plan.pdf";
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hello</p>');
$mpdf->Output($path, "F");
exit;
```

But this piece of code returns an error like this :

mPDF error: Unable to create output file: sites/default/files/diet_plans/diet_plan.pdf

Comment: Not enough information. Does that path exist, as a sub-path from your current working folder? Do you have read/write permission?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that mPDF can not create directories.  I have been using Rules to create the directory first and then execute the mPDF action. Make sure that the Directory diet_plans exists